# Regex: extract an entry multiple times

Tags: java, regex

Consider I have a string like:

`Hi, <@W12313>, <@U333111>!`

I need to extract all matches with pattern `<@([WU].+?)>.+` so I will get list of `["W12313", "U333111"]`. I matched a single one successfully but I don't know how to extract it into a list.

I use Java flavor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<@([WU][^>]*)>` regex with the following code:

```
String s = "Hi, <@W12313>, <@U333111>!";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<@([WU][^>]*)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    res.add(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
System.out.println(res);
// => [W12313, U333111]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Ri5OxW) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5CLVx/1).

The pattern matches

- `<@` - a `<@` substring
- `([WU][^>]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[WU]` - `W` or `U` and then
  - `[^>]*` - a negated character class matching 0+ chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

If there can be only digits after `W` or `U`, replace `[^>]*` with `[0-9]*`.

If there can be any ASCII uppercase char after `@`, replace `[WU]` with `[A-Z]`.